# JSON deserialize from RestSharp

Tags: json, restsharp

I have the following JSON coming from Wistia and want to make a list out of it

```
[
  {
     "id":1568823,
     "name":"Borrowed Video",
     "mediaCount":1,
     "created":"2015-04-14T19:27:21+00:00",
     "updated":"2015-04-14T19:28:46+00:00",
     "hashedId":"wm5j416urg",
     "anonymousCanUpload":false,
     "anonymousCanDownload":false,
     "public":true,
     "publicId":"wm5j416urg",
     "description":null
  },
  {
    "id":1592682,"name":
    "Untitled Project",
    "mediaCount":0,
    "created":"2015-04-23T15:27:26+00:00",
    "updated":"2015-04-23T15:27:26+00:00",
    "hashedId":"6ktqeybwa3",
    "anonymousCanUpload":false,
    "anonymousCanDownload":false,
    "public":true,
    "publicId":"6ktqeybwa3",
    "description":null
  }
]
```

I have a `Project` class and a `ProjectList` class (which is a list of `Project`s). My code gives me only null values for the data part of the response.

```
 IRestResponse<Wistia.Models.ListProject> response = client.Execute<Wistia.Models.ListProject>(request);
```

What am I missing?

Comment: That JSON represents an array so you may need to do something like `IRestResponse<List<Wistia.Models.ListProject>>`. It would help if you posted the code for `Wistia.Models.ListProject` to make sure the receiving class is even correctly defined.

Comment: @CraigW.- thanks that helped me visualize it